# Receiving error when I try to start a Scrapy project

Tags: python, scrapy, conda

I'm trying to start a new project using Scrapy on MAC OS, and after creating a new conda environment and installing scrapy, I can't get the startproject function to work.

In my environment, I run...

```
scrapy startproject scraper
```

Then, I receive this traceback.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/alexmcgraw/opt/anaconda3/envs/espn_daily_sport_env/bin/scrapy", line 5, in <module>
    from scrapy.cmdline import execute
  File "/Users/alexmcgraw/opt/anaconda3/envs/espn_daily_sport_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scrapy/cmdline.py", line 9, in <module>
    from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
  File "/Users/alexmcgraw/opt/anaconda3/envs/espn_daily_sport_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scrapy/crawler.py", line 18, in <module>
    from scrapy.core.engine import ExecutionEngine
  File "/Users/alexmcgraw/opt/anaconda3/envs/espn_daily_sport_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scrapy/core/engine.py", line 14, in <module>
    from scrapy.core.scraper import Scraper
  File "/Users/alexmcgraw/opt/anaconda3/envs/espn_daily_sport_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scrapy/core/scraper.py", line 16, in <module>
    from scrapy.utils.log import failure_to_exc_info, logformatter_adapter
  File "/Users/alexmcgraw/opt/anaconda3/envs/espn_daily_sport_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scrapy/utils/log.py", line 12, in <module>
    from scrapy.utils.versions import scrapy_components_versions
  File "/Users/alexmcgraw/opt/anaconda3/envs/espn_daily_sport_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scrapy/utils/versions.py", line 12, in <module>
    from scrapy.utils.ssl import get_openssl_version
  File "/Users/alexmcgraw/opt/anaconda3/envs/espn_daily_sport_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/scrapy/utils/ssl.py", line 1, in <module>
    import OpenSSL
  File "/Users/alexmcgraw/opt/anaconda3/envs/espn_daily_sport_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/OpenSSL/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from OpenSSL import crypto, SSL
  File "/Users/alexmcgraw/opt/anaconda3/envs/espn_daily_sport_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/OpenSSL/crypto.py", line 11, in <module>
    from OpenSSL._util import (
  File "/Users/alexmcgraw/opt/anaconda3/envs/espn_daily_sport_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/OpenSSL/_util.py", line 5, in <module>
    from cryptography.hazmat.bindings.openssl.binding import Binding
  File "/Users/alexmcgraw/opt/anaconda3/envs/espn_daily_sport_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/cryptography/hazmat/bindings/openssl/binding.py", line 14, in <module>
    from cryptography.hazmat.bindings._openssl import ffi, lib
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/alexmcgraw/opt/anaconda3/envs/espn_daily_sport_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/_cffi_backend.cpython-38-darwin.so, 0x0002): Library not loaded: @rpath/libffi.7.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/alexmcgraw/opt/anaconda3/envs/espn_daily_sport_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/_cffi_backend.cpython-38-darwin.so
  Reason: tried: '/Users/alexmcgraw/opt/anaconda3/envs/espn_daily_sport_env/lib/libffi.7.dylib' (no such file), '/Users/alexmcgraw/opt/anaconda3/envs/espn_daily_sport_env/lib/libffi.7.dylib' (no such file), '/Users/alexmcgraw/opt/anaconda3/envs/espn_daily_sport_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/../../libffi.7.dylib' (no such file), '/Users/alexmcgraw/opt/anaconda3/envs/espn_daily_sport_env/lib/libffi.7.dylib' (no such file), '/Users/alexmcgraw/opt/anaconda3/envs/espn_daily_sport_env/lib/libffi.7.dylib' (no such file), '/Users/alexmcgraw/opt/anaconda3/envs/espn_daily_sport_env/lib/python3.8/site-packages/../../libffi.7.dylib' (no such file), '/opt/concourse/worker/volumes/live/903ea60a-0489-485f-6f93-162648469061/volume/python_1573076474316/_h_env_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehol/lib/libffi.7.dylib' (no such file), '/opt/concourse/worker/volumes/live/903ea60a-0489-485f-6f93-162648469061/volume/python_1573076474316/_h_env_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehol/lib/libffi.7.dylib' (no such file), '/Users/alexmcgraw/opt/anaconda3/envs/espn_daily_sport_env/bin/../lib/libffi.7.dylib' (no such file), '/opt/concourse/worker/volumes/live/903ea60a-0489-485f-6f93-162648469061/volume/python_1573076474316/_h_env_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehol/lib/libffi.7.dylib' (no such file), '/opt/concourse/worker/volumes/live/903ea60a-0489-485f-6f93-162648469061/volume/python_1573076474316/_h_env_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehold_placehol/lib/libffi.7.dylib' (no such file), '/Users/alexmcgraw/opt/anaconda3/envs/espn_daily_sport_env/bin/../lib/libffi.7.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/local/lib/libffi.7.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/lib/libffi.7.dylib' (no such file)
```

I'm not quite sure what I'm looking at with this error, and my searching on Google/Stackoverflow has been to no avail. Any idea why I can't start a new scrapy project in my environment?

Comment: Try installing scrapy with pip3

Comment: I've tried running this, and it tells me all requirements are already satisified

Answer (score 0):

your os is Mac, I think, try those commands:

```
brew update
brew upgrade
brew cleanup
```

Comment: Yep, my OS is Mac. My bad, forgot to include that.

Comment: I found another solution like @albi says  "Try installing scrapy with pip3"

Comment: I've tried running this, and it tells me all requirements are already satisified

Comment: I've encountered this problem one day and the solution for me was to run using sudo.